# C - Issue with random number generator

Tags: c, pointers, random, numbers, generator

I have an issue while generating a random number and giving the value to a pointer.

What I want to do here: generate a number between 1 and 1000, and the player will receive that amount of gold.
The base gold is 0 obviously.
Although, for some reason, when I printf the amount of integer gold, there were cases when it was more than 3000, which is obviously a sign of error.

The goldchange part is because the player will receive gold lots of times and I want it to work every time. Although at the moment, since I am testing this part of my program, the player receives gold only once.

Since I am a beginner programmer, I guess I am doing it wrong.
How should I do this correctly so integer GOLD will have the correct value?

```
int* gold=0;
int* goldchange;
srand(time(0));
goldchange=gold;
gold=gold+rand()%1000+1;
goldchange=gold-goldchange;
printf("You have received the following amount of gold: %d", goldchange);

printf("You have this many golds: %d", gold);
```

So, for example, this was what happened last time:
You have received the following amount of gold: 777
You have this many golds: 3108

But it should be 777 not 3108....
(obviously every run gives different numbers, but the two values are never the same...)

Comment: `gold` is a pointer so `gold=gold+rand()%1000+1;` makes no sense. There doesn't seem any reason to declare `gold` as a pointer. Perhaps just replace `int* gold = 0` with `int gold = 0`.

Comment: @JohnColeman I feel so dumb now. Thank you. I have no idea why I wanted to do it as a pointer. I changed  both goldchange and gold from pointer into a normal integer and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring to variables as pointers with:

```
int* gold=0;
int* goldchange;
```

And then proceeding to treat these as regular `int` variables. In the given code I see no reason for declaring these variables as pointers. Why not just

```
int gold=0;
int goldchange;
```

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you! I will accept this as an answer as soon as I can!

Answer (score 2):

As John Coleman mentioned `gold` is a pointer and you need to allocate memory for it.

```
int* gold=0;
int* goldchange = 0;

gold  = malloc(sizeof(int));
if(0 == gold) 
    return;//Handle this case in your application.

goldchange = malloc(sizeof(int));
if(0 == goldchange) 
    return;//Handle this case in your application.

srand(time(0));
*goldchange = *gold;
*gold = *gold + rand()%1000+1;
*goldchange = *gold - *goldchange;
printf("You have received the following amount of gold: %d", *goldchange);

printf("You have this many golds: %d", *gold);
```

Comment: If you don't need pointers you can use the solution given by 
John Coleman.

Comment: This is a good answer for the case when OP needs the variables to be pointers for some other purpose (not shown in the posted code), so +1